# ruby way to turn "abcd" into "a b c d " (eg pad each char with spaces)

Tags: ruby, string

I see how to remove excess spaces, but dont see a simple way (other than manually iterating) to turn the string "happy" into "h a p p y " (with or without that last space doesn't matter)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regex would be an easy way:

```
'happy'.gsub(/./) { |m| m + ' ' }
# "h a p p y "
```

Or a few more:

```
'happy'.gsub(/./) { |m| m + ' ' }.strip # No trailing space.
'happy'.gsub(/./) { $& + ' ' }          # Trailing space, uses global $& variable.
'happy'.gsub(/./) { $& + ' ' }.strip    # Ues global variable, no trailing space.
'happy'.chars.to_a.join(' ')            # No regex, no trailing space.
'happy'.split('').join(' ')             # No regex, no trailing space.
```

I kinda' like the `split`/`join` one myself.

Comment: @bricker: I like the way it looks, nice and easy to grok at a glance.

Comment: It's not as fast as `chars.to_a.join`, but much faster than any of the `gsub` methods. Check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I was curious so I benchmarked each of mu's answers (100,000 times each)... `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin10.8.0]`:

```
'happy'.gsub(/./) { |m| m + ' ' }.strip
  2.160000   0.010000   2.170000 (  2.176177)

'happy'.gsub(/./) { $& + ' ' }
  2.220000   0.010000   2.230000 (  2.264467)

'happy'.gsub(/./) { $& + ' ' }.strip
  2.480000   0.010000   2.490000 (  2.490261)

'happy'.chars.to_a.join(' ')
  1.040000   0.000000   1.040000 (  1.055694)

'happy'.split('').join(' ') 
  1.350000   0.010000   1.360000 (  1.354991)
```

Comment: +1 for the benchmarking but if any of these are your app's bottleneck then you're probably doing okay :)

Comment: No harm in knowing which is fastest, though!